# Could I embed a link to display a PDF in a browser, rather than induce a download?

Tags: html, pdf, browser, embed

I would like customers to my website be able to click on a url/button on my website, and then have the url/button open a submittable PDF IN THE BROWSER, rather than induce a download. Not sure on the code specifics that need to be added to make the PDF display in the browser, rather than be queued into active downloads...Thank you

Best,
SL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
<iframe id="myFrame" style="display:none" width="600" height="300"></iframe>
<input type="button" value="Open PDF" onclick = "openPdf()"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
function openPdf()
{
var omyFrame = document.getElementById("myFrame");
omyFrame.style.display="block";
omyFrame.src = "2.pdf";
}
</script>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Time ago, when I had to solve the same problem, the issue came when some users didn´t have installed the Adobe (or other PDF viewer) plug-in in their browser. 
Just keep it in mind and maybe it´s interesting to provide a link to download the PDF Viewer of your preference.
I think, no special code is required on your side. The browser will take care but likely you cannot forcé the user to view it on the browser and not download. He will always have the option to choose. If you really want to avoid that you should look at the options your PDF is generated with.